# How can I get the music file to play in the final animated version?

Tags: animation

when I animate my video the music doesn't play in the final saved version, even though it plays ok in Blender before animating. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling the audio codec located under the render tab:
[image]